# jQuery Greater than and Smaller than check

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, logical-operators

This is my form:

```
<form class="fms-quote-form" action="https://web.com/quotes" method="get">
<input name="wpf126904_18" id="fms-zip" type="number" placeholder="Enter your Zipcode">
<input type="submit" value="Get My Rates">
</form>
```

And this my jQuery that's **not** working:

```
$('.fms-quote-form').submit(function() {

if ( $('#fms-zip').val() >= 90000 AND <=96162 ) {
  return true;
} else {
    window.open('https://smartfinancial.com/auto-insurance-rates', '_blank');
    return false;
  }
});
```

How do I (i) check that the value of #fms-zip is greater than 90000 and smaller than 96162 to submit the form, and (ii) redirect the user to another website if any other value is entered?

Look forward to your input :)

Comment: You have to use && instead of AND

Comment: Always check the error console!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always check the error console - you're assuming syntax that is faulty. `AND` will be throwing an error - you need `&&`.

What's more, you can't just specify your higher number and assume JavaScript will know to compare it against the same subject value you compared the lower value against - you have to repeat the subject.

```
let val = parseInt($('#fms-zip').val());
if (val >= 90000 && val <= 96162 ) { //<-- note 2 references to @val
```

As @Alessio Cantarella points out, you also need to cast the value to a number - reading the field's value returns a string.

Answer (score 1):

To check if ZIP is greater than 90000 and smaller than 96162, you need to use:

- [`parseInt` function](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp) to convert `#fms-zip`'s `value` to an integer
- [`&&` logic operator](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp) to check that both conditions are valid.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.fms-quote-form').submit(function() {
    let zip = parseInt($('#fms-zip').val());
    let isZipValid = zip >= 90000 && zip <= 96162;
    if (isZipValid) {
      return true;
    } else {
      window.open('https://smartfinancial.com/auto-insurance-rates', '_blank');
      return false;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="fms-quote-form" action="https://web.com/quotes" method="get">
  <input name="wpf126904_18" id="fms-zip" type="number" placeholder="Enter your Zipcode">
  <input type="submit" value="Get My Rates">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

**You can try like this -**

```
$(function() {
  $('.fms-quote-form').submit(function() {
    var valueZip= parseInt($('#fms-zip').val());

    if (valueZip >= 90000 && valueZip <= 96162) {
      return true;
    } else {
      window.open('https://smartfinancial.com/auto-insurance-rates', '_blank');
      return false;
    }
  });
});
```